# Inexpensive USB-C 3.1 splitter / hub for charging

Tags: usb, hub, splitters

I got the new MacBook and it runs amazingly, and I got Apple's USB-C to USB-A adapter. Connected to it I have an USB 3.0 Hub with a mouse, headphones, external HD, and 2 Xbox controllers.

My only issue is that I cannot charge and use my external USB devices at the same time.

I looked pretty hard to find a reasonably priced USB-C splitter but all I could find is [Apple's $79 3 way splitter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter).

What are your recommendations for a reasonably priced (preferably less than or equal to $20) USB-C 3.1 splitter?
(1 USB type C input -> 2 USB type C outputs)

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for, I am looking for a splitter with a USBC input and 2 USBC outputs.

Comment: So your hub is USB-C, not USB-A?

Comment: My hub is USBA, but I already have an adapter for that.  I just need another USBC port so I can use this adapter (which the hub is connected to) and charge my computer at the same time.

Comment: Would it work to get a new hub with a USB-C input (connect to MacBook) and a combination of USB-A and USB-C outputs?  Do all ports need USB 3.0 speed?  Do all ports need to charge?